# How to set up SSL for a Go API Server on GCE while static hosting Frontend on Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I'm currently having an issue with setting up SSL for my API server written in Go and hosted on Google Cloud Engine (GCE). My frontend is a React application statically hosted on Google Cloud Storage.

Initially, my backend and frontend were communicating perfectly fine over HTTP. However, for security reasons, I've decided to switch to HTTPS, but I am encountering issues.

Here is my backend code in Go:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, World")
}

func getAPI(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization")
    log.Println("ゲットできた") 
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Get request received") 
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Go Test!!")

    http.HandleFunc("/", handler) 

    http.HandleFunc("/get", getAPI)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

And my frontend React code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isSuccess, setSuccess] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://00.000.00.000:8080/get')
        .then(response => {
          if(response.ok) {
            setSuccess(true);
            setLoading(false);
            return response.text();
          } else {
            throw new Error("Error in fetching");
          }
        })
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(error => {
          setError(true);
          setLoading(false);
          console.error('Error:', error);
        });
  }, []);

  return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            {isLoading && 'Loading...'}
            {isSuccess && 'Success!'}
            {isError && 'An error occurred!'}
          </p>
          <a
              className="App-link"
              href="https://reactjs.org"
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </header>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I change the request from HTTP to HTTPS in my React code, I get the following error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

I tried to follow the steps in this Japanese blog (https://zenn.dev/knockknock/articles/10aa24fde47c45) to set up an SSL certificate, but it didn't work. The blog seems to assume both the frontend and backend are on GCE, which is not the case for me.

I'm seeking advice on how to setup SSL for my Go API server on GCE while my React frontend is statically hosted on Cloud Storage. I would appreciate any information or articles similar to my architecture.

For now, my primary goal is to get my local React development server (npm start) working with HTTPS requests.

[image]

Comment: I strongly recommend 2 things: Firstly, use a HTTPS Load balancer to route the traffic either to Cloud Storage when the front path is used or to the containerized backend. In addition, you won't have CORS issue, because you will use the same URL for the front and the back (abstracted with the LB). Secondly, the containerized backed could greatly feat Cloud Run and sidecar container.